# Jest cannot read property 'instances' of undefined when mocking es6 classes

Tags: node.js, jestjs

Trying to mock ES6 class, just to get a dummy mock I can spy on. My code seems to follow the documentation quite closely, but I get this error when calling `.mock` on my dummy:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'instances' of undefined

```
jest.mock('../../../adapters/Cache')
const Fizz = require('../Fizz')
const Cache = require('../../../adapters/Cache')

const fizz = new Fizz()

describe('CACHE', () => {
  it('should return a mock', () => {
    //This is the line that fails
    const mockCache = Cache.mock.instances[0]

    const mockRetrieveRecords = mockCache.retrieveRecords
    fizz.doStuff()
    expect(mockRetrieveRecords).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
  })
})
```

Comment: Could you try `jest.mock('../../../adapters/Cache', () => jest.fn())`

Comment: @AndreasKöberle still no work. `mockCache` is still undefined. The error message says "cannot  read property 'retrieveRecords' of undefined"

Answer (score 2):

`jest.mock('../../../adapters/Cache')` will mock the module with just `undefined`. To mock a module that returns a class you could create a mock that just returns a function which returns the mocked instance. To set make the `retrieveRecords` a spy that you can access in the test, you have to mock the module with an empty spy, import it and set the real mock:

```
jest.mock('../../../adapters/Cache', () => jest.fn())
const Cache = require('../../../adapters/Cache')
const Fizz = require('../Fizz')

const retrieveRecords = jest.fn()
Cache.mockImplementation(() => ({retrieveRecords})



describe('CACHE', () => {
  it('should return a mock', () => {
    const fizz = new Fizz()
    fizz.doStuff()
    expect(retrieveRecords).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
  })
})
```